# Regex for checking correct string format

Tags: regex, string

I have a regex:

```
( )?(1)?[0-9]\.[0-5][0-9](a|p|n|m)( )?-( )?(1)?[0-9]\.[0-5][0-9](a|p|n|m)(\n)?
```

The expression above is a time format: `h.nna`,

where :

- `h` is the one- or two-digit hour
- `nn` is the two-digit minute section of time; and
- `a` is the period of day (`a` or `p` for antemeridian or postmeridian, respectively; and `n` for noon and `m` for midnight)
- the time is in 12-hour format

Suppose the string input is `19.24p-12.00p` (we know that 19.24 is invalid for 12-hour format and there's no such thing as 12.00p), this will appear valid on the assigned expression. How can I modify my regex in such a way that when the hour is two-digit, the digits would be just 1 `[0-2]`, not the `[0-9]` declared above. Also, how can I make `n` and `m` period of the day valid only for 12.00?

Thanks.

Comment: `there's no such thing as 12.00p` -- really? There's no such thing as 12:00 PM?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud He said that there will be `n` for noon and `m` for midnight. So `12:00 PM` is `12:00m`

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer, okay I gotcha.

Comment: You will have to modify the referenced duplicate a little, but that should not be too hard.

Comment: 19.24 is invalid for 24-hour format? Please explain...

Comment: Sorry guys, I should have said "12-hour" format. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regex (PCRE compatible):

```
^(12\.00[mn]|12(\.[0-5]\d)[ap]|00\g'2'a|([0]?[1-9]|1[0-1])\g'2'[ap])-\g'1'$
```

This will match **00.00a** to **00.59a** as it should.

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/iG9fF9)